# About the 10th Graha and the 1100 planets whose leaded by Ketu

Tags: identification-request, astrology, navagraha

Most of us know that totally 9 planets (Navagrahas) and Bhumi (earth) also the planet, but not worshipped as Graha.

However, I have sometimes heard that there was a 10th Graha named Jamatha (means son-in-law). But, it is true? Did any scripture mentiones there was any 10th planet?

---

Meanwhile, [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626839.html) Skanda Purana mentiones that Ketu become the lord of 1100 planets:-

> 5. Mahādeva was pleased with him (Ketu) and granted him the status of a Planet and also the overlordship of **eleven hundred Grahas (Planets)**.

What are these planets? (I didn't ask all 1100 planets, you can give at least some of them)

Comment: Jamata Dashamo Grahah is a satirical statement to mean "one's son-in-law will trouble one like the Navagrahas" - not to be taken literally.